# Is it possible in Swift to return an Int and a list of int at the same time?

Tags: swift, list, int, option-type, identifier

I have to write a function in Swift where I need create a list of int if the counter is different to 0. 
Here is my code in Swift :

```
func compteurZeros(cellule:[[Int]]) -> (compteur:Int, liste:(Int))
{
    var compteur = 0;
    for i in 0...2
    {
        for j in 0...2
        {
            if(cellule[i][j] == 0)
            {
                compteur = compteur+1
            }
        }
    }
    print(compteur)
    if (compteur != 0)
    {
        for i in 0..<(compteur) {
            var liste:(Int)
        }
    }
    return (compteur, liste!)
}
```

But, in the return, I've got this error :

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'liste'
        return (compteur, liste!)
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The scope of `liste` is confined inside the `for loop` within the `if statement`, so when you return it, `liste` no longer exists. Also you do nothing with `liste` inside the `for loop`.

Comment: `(Int)` also isn't a list. It's a 1-tuple of `Int`, which is the same as just `Int`. I think you mean `[Int]` here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What is the value of `liste` supposed to be? You don't even compute a value for it

Comment: Yes, the purpose of this function is to create a list for every value of "compteur". For example, if compteur = 5, I need to create 5 lists.

Comment: So you need a 2D array, `[[Int]]`, so you get a list of lists?

Comment: I need this 2D array because i'm working in a matrix. The "compteur" is counting all the 0 present in this 2D array. If a 0 is found, I need to create a liste

Comment: @EstelleT Creating an array an array doesn't sound like "counting zeros" to me. That's a misplaced responsibility. This function should count zeros. It should be another functions' job to use that count.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your function somewhat so that it returns an [[Int]] as the second element in the tuple

```
func compteurZeros(cellule:[[Int]]) -> (compteur:Int, liste:[[Int]]) {
    var compteur = 0;
    for i in 0...2
    {
        for j in 0...2
        {
            if(cellule[i][j] == 0)
            {
                compteur = compteur+1
            }
        }
    }

    var liste = [[Int]]()
    if (compteur != 0)
    {
        for i in 0..<(compteur) {
            liste.append([])
        }
    }
    return (compteur, liste)
}
```

Now this code is not the best so it can be improved by skipping the loops

```
func compteurZeros(cellule:[[Int]]) -> (compteur:Int, liste:[[Int]]) {
    let compteur = cellule.flatMap {$0}.filter {$0 == 0}.count
    let liste:[[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: compteur)

    return (compteur, liste)
}
```

Since the value `compteur` is redundant this can be further simplified to

```
func compteurZeros(cellule:[[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    return Array(repeating: [], count: cellule.flatMap {$0}.filter {$0 == 0}.count)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think that I've understand why it didn't work !

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I meant to address them to OP, but I forgot to tag them. I'll delete my comment and repost it with OP tagged.

Comment: @EstelleT Why is it that you only count `0`s within the first `0...2` rows, and first `0...2` columns? What if cellule ("cell" in english?) is empty?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica the cell cannot be empty because it depends of another big matrix 9x9. With the big matrix, I create 9 little matrix 3x3

Comment: @EstelleT Is this a part of a sudoku program? Anyway, those don't seem like appropriate properties of a function called "countZeros". Count zeros should count all zeros in a given collection. Whether or not you put in a collection that's 3x3 or 2x706, or empty, that's up to th ecaller.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica yes it is. I want to create a list of possible value for each 0 in the matrix. If the list contains only one element it could be the great one.